# Testing a relation between a categorical variable and a muticategorical set

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, multiple-response

I have a dataset with two variables: the response variable is the use of a fish species as a food resource, and the explanatory variable is the profession:

| Person | Profession | Use of fish |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Fisherman | Often |
| John | Bus driver | Often |
| Mary | Fisherman | Rarely |
| Joseph | Joiner | Occasionally |
| Martha | Waitress | Occasionally |
| Martha | Fisherman | Occasionally |
| Harry | Fisherman | Rarely |
| Thomas | Waiter | Often |
| Thomas | Mason | Often |
| Harold | Fisherman | Rarely |
| Harold | Mason | Rarely |
| Harold | Carpenter | Rarely |
| Christopher | Fisherman | Occasionally |
| Christopher | Bus driver | Occasionally |

Note that `Profession` variable is repeated sometimes, since the same person may have two or more professions. Which statistical test should I use to compare `Professions`  with regard to `Use of fish` or associate Profession with the Use? Could it be a Chi-square?

Comment: One way to go with the investigation of the relation between Y=Use and X=Prof is to regress Y by X. Convert your data from "long" to "wide" structure: each Person is single row. Create a set of binary variables, each variable = one Prof, with values 1 (yes) or 0 (no). This is the predictors X. Perform multinomial regression of Y on X. For the analysis to be viable you must have consuderably more persons than professions, otherwise cut the number of professions first.

Comment: If it were not that one person in your data may have multiple professions then this analysis would in fact come to usual chi-square.

Comment: Please observe how I've edited your title and tags. I replaced "repeated measures" with "multiple response". It is a question where a respondent can select more than one variant of a categorical response. I consider this better than "repeated measures" because in repeated measures the measured value might repeat or be different. Here, same profession cannot repeat for the same respondent. If you don't like my changes, please feel free to roll back.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I really had thought to turn each profession into a binary variable, but I still didn't know if that would be adequate, or which test I could use.

Comment: I found your changes in my question very pertinent, thank you very much for that too!